# Error when using useEffect API call in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

I am calling this api inside a context provider:

```
const url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/posts/'

const PostListContextProvider = (props) => {
    const [posts, setPosts] = useState([])

    useEffect(async () => {
        const {data} = await axios.get(url);
        setPosts(data)
    }, [posts]);

    return (
        <PostListContext.Provider value={ posts }>
            { props.children }
        </PostListContext.Provider>
    );
}
```

Upon consuming the context using useContext, this error occurs:

```
react-dom.development.js:19710 Uncaught TypeError: destroy is not a function
```

What am I doing wrong?

ps.even though I am getting the error, I am still successfully fetching the data

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting error after i put Async function in useEffect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58495238/getting-error-after-i-put-async-function-in-useeffect)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`useEffect` should not be `async`

Do it like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
        (async () => {
          const {data} = await axios.get(url);
          setPosts(data)
        })()
}, [posts]);
```

Comment: The reason why you can't use an async function is because that makes the function return a `Promise`, and `useEffect` requires that if you return something it should be a function, which it can use to clean up the effect.

Answer (score 2):

`useEffect` is supposed to `return a function` if it returns something, since you are defining the callback function to useEffect as a promise, what it essentially returns is a promise which is not what it expects.

In order to use a async function within useEffect you would write it like

```
useEffect(() => {

   async function myFn() {
        const {data} = await axios.get(url);
        setPosts(data)
   }
   myFn();
}, [posts]);
```

Comment: I am still getting the error. Its actually a warning, and it shows that react still assumes I use the previous method

Comment: I didn't get you. What is the warning exactly

Comment: my bad. I forgot to save. Thanks!