# "Uncaught TypeError: destroy is not a function" Error in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Now I'm building the application using React.js. All pages are working excepting of auth page. After logging successfully, it should bring the user to the home page but it was broken, and showed the blank page. After refreshing the manually, it started to show the home page.

When I checked the application thru development tools in the chrome browser, it says `"Uncaught TypeError: destroy is not a function"`.
I attached the code where caused the error.

```
...
const UnauthedWrapper = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const location = useLocation();
  const {
    state: { auth, user },
  } = useContext(AppContext);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (auth && user && user.emailVerified && user.dstoreName) {
      navigate(`/app/overview`);
      return null;
    }
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [auth, user]);

  return (
    <>
      {!location.pathname.includes("/auth") ? (
        <Header
          logo="/images/logo.png"
          page="landing"
          hideLogin={process.env.REACT_APP_ENV === "PROD"}
        />
      ) : (
        <Link to="/">
          <img
            src="/images/logo.png"
            alt="logo"
            className="logo ms-4 mt-4"
            width={180}
          />
        </Link>
      )}
     ...
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting error after I put Async function in useEffect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58495238/getting-error-after-i-put-async-function-in-useeffect)

Comment: In my case I had mistakenly used useEffect instead of useMemo

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It turns out this almost always happens when you try to return anything from your `useEffect` hook that is not a function.

- **Why Doesn’t This Work?**

If you return anything from a useEffect function, it must be a function.

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (auth && user && user.emailVerified && user.dstoreName) {
      navigate(`/app/overview`);
      return null;
    }
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [auth, user]);
```

- **The Quick Solution**

1. Remove the unnecessary return.

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (auth && user && user.emailVerified && user.dstoreName) {
      navigate(`/app/overview`);
    }
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [auth, user]);
```

2. Make sure it has function.

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (auth && user && user.emailVerified && user.dstoreName) {
      navigate(`/app/overview`);
      return () => {}
    }
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [auth, user]);
```

Comment: _"If you return anything from a useEffect function, it must be a function."_ - **not true.** You can return `undefined` or just nothing: `return;`. The no-op function `() => {}` is unnecessary.

Answer (score 31):

In my case, I had the `useEffect` callback as an async function.

```
useEffect(async () =>{
 // code here...
},[])
```

So I created the function as a standalone and called it inside `useEffect`.

```
const doSomething = async() =>{
// code here...
}

useEffect(() =>{
 doSomething();
},[])
```

Comment: This was my case too. Turns out useEffect does not like that async keyword in its declaration.

Answer (score 5):

**The best answer is to return without any return value.**

```
return;
```

Or in your case:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (auth && user?.emailVerified && user?.dstoreName) {
      navigate(`/app/overview`);
    }
  }, [auth, user?.emailVerified, user?.dstoreName]);
```

Notice that I have no return statement at all. Or you can use a guard clause:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!auth || !user?.emailVerified || !user?.dstoreName) return;
    navigate(`/app/overview`);
  }, [auth, user?.emailVerified, user?.dstoreName]);
```

React is just a layer over JavaScript, so when a function has no return statement, or the value-less return statement (usually as part of a conditional), it returns `undefined`.

This is functionally equivalent to the explicit `return undefined;`, and React will ignore any undefined destroy function. But it will complain if you return `null` as a destroy function, because `null` in JavaScript is a defined value.

**PS:** I removed `// eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps` because you can check the properties of `user` object for changes, instead of checking the user object. It's actually less prone to bugs that way because you compare actual values, not the object reference. It's possible to change the properties of an existing object without changing the reference, which would not fire the hook. **That's the reason why ESLint warns you about Exhaustive Deps!**

---

*How did I get here?* In my case I hit this problem because I tried to write a useEffect hook like this: `useEffect(() => myAsyncFunc(myVal), [myVal]);` but it wouldn't work because myAsyncFunc returns a Promise which cannot be a destroy function. The fix is to wrap `myAsyncFunc(myVal)` in curly braces `{}` which ensures it returns undefined:

```
useEffect(() => {
  myAsyncFunc(myVal);
}, [myVal]);
```

Answer (score 4):

This error occurs because your "destroy" or "componentWillUnmount" returned by the callback in `useEffect` is not a function:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (auth && user && user.emailVerified && user.dstoreName) {
      navigate(`/app/overview`);
      return null; // NOT A FUNCTION
    }
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [auth, user]);
```

So you'll have to change that to something that *is* a function, or don't return there at all.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (auth && user && user.emailVerified && user.dstoreName) {
      navigate(`/app/overview`);
      return () => {}; // no-op
    }
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [auth, user]);
```

Comment: _"you'll have to change that to something that is a function, or don't return there at all"_ - **not true.** You can return `undefined` or just nothing: `return;`. The no-op function `() => {}` is unnecessary.

Answer (score 3):

I just removed async from useEffect and it worked for me.
This was the code which was giving the same error.

```
useEffect(async () => {
    if (!localStorage.getItem(process.env.REACT_APP_LOCALHOST_KEY)) {
        navigate("/login");
    }
}, []);
```

Answer (score 1):

just remove the return if there is not a function to return, in my case I had a useEffect for a reduce dispatch and I just removed the return and it fixed it:

```
useEffect(()=> {
   dispatch(fetchPostsAction())
  }, [dispatch])
```

There is no return

Comment: This will not work if the author needs to return something; there is already an accepted answer, more clear and effective. Please read [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 1):

**if you're write Direct async in useEffect:** Putting `async` **directly** in `useEffect()` can lead to unexpected behavior and errors, especially when **updating** state within it.

```js
const abc = ({children}) => {
const [user,setUser]=useState(undefined);
 

useEffect(async()=>{
    try {
        const activeUser = await currentUser({})
        console.log(activeUser);
        setUser({...activeUser})
        
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}

},[])
```

**with in a state updates inside async**: React has strict rules about state updates with in hooks. Updating user state directly within the `async` function might violate those rules,use the:

**Create an inner async function**  `takeTime(){}` within useEffect. Call load explicitly to ensure proper execution and asunc **state updates like** .

```js
const  abc = ({children}) => {
const [user,setUser]=useState(undefined);
 

useEffect(()=>{


async function takeTime(){
    try {
        const activeUser = currentUser({})
        console.log(activeUser);
        setUser({...activeUser})
        
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        setUser(undefined)
    }
}

takeTime();// Call the await function to initiate user fetching

},[])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const check = ()=>{
   if (auth && user && user.emailVerified && user.dstoreName) {
      navigate(`/app/overview`);
      return () => {}
    }
}

useEffect(() => {
  check()
        // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [auth, user]);
```

> put the code you have in useEffect as it own function

Answer (score -3):

The simple solution for this is Instead of using useEffect please use useState

I had also stucked with this and got solution

happy coding...!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The solution you provided is incorrect, as `useEffect` and `useState` are two different react hooks and are used for different use cases.