# Uncaught run time error , destroy is not a function TypeError: destroy is not a function

Tags: reactjs, runtime-error, typeerror

I am building a  page using react , everything is working properly but when I am routing from one page to another this error is shown , Then i have to refresh this page manually after that error is gone , but again try to reach another page same thing is happening .[This error is coming after routing from one page to another](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q177L.png)

This is the code for home page I am adding it , I donot know from where error is happening , Please help me finding it

//Home

Comment: Hi, can you please share your code? We can't help much if you don't share the code that's causing the issue (you don't need to share everything, just enough to create a [mre])

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74265321/uncaught-typeerror-destroy-is-not-a-function-error-in-react

check if this helps.

Comment: Mostly I saw this error for `useEffect` having async function as param instead of having it inside its callback ,... I mean `useEffect(async function Me(){})` for `useEffect(()=>async function Me(){})` .... if that's the case you could find it by searching the useEffect without callback in your entire codebase

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.